# Java -> Mysql: get INT doesnt work?

Tags: java, mysql

In my DB theres a field named 'failcounter' and its an int.

Which query i have to use to receive the int?

i tried with:

```
SELECT `failcounter` FROM `randomstuff`
```

and tried to receive the int with:

```
  if(zrs.next()){
     return zrs.getInt(1);
  }else{
      return -99;
  }
```

but im not able to get the int.

Whats wrong? =)

Here is the whole method, maybe theres something wrong:

```
  public static int getFailCounter() throws Exception {
        try {
          // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          // Setup the connection with the DB
          connect = DriverManager.getConnection(""+MyBot.mysqlDbPath+"",""+MyBot.mysqlDbUsername+"",""+MyBot.mysqlDbPassword+"");
          PreparedStatement zpst=null;
          ResultSet zrs=null;
          zpst=connect.prepareStatement("SELECT `failcounter` FROM `randomstuff`");
          zrs=zpst.executeQuery();
          if(zrs.next()){
             return zrs.getInt(1);
          }else{
              return -99;
          }
        }catch (Exception e) {
              throw e;
            } finally {
              close();
            }
      }
```

Comment: Everything seems OK. Does the program throw some exception? If yes, post the full stack trace

Comment: "*not able to get the int*" is neither a valid Java compiler error, nor a valid Java exception nor a valid MySQL error message.

Comment: May be the column is not of type that can be obtained as an int.

Comment: Well thats the Question, there isnt any Exception so idk whats wrong :/

Comment: What value do you get instead?

Comment: then, you don't have the record in the resultset. that's it.. what happens when you run this query directly in the server?

Comment: and this could be caused by what? im little confused right now

Comment: why are you using quoting marks in your query? Isn't it supposed to be SELECT failcounter FROM randomstuff?

Comment: I just posted the whole method above in my post. Maybe it helps

Comment: as @R.J and I said, remove the single quotes/backticks from your query.

Comment: Does `randomstuff` actually contain any rows?

Comment: @R.J Why would that work, AFAIK the backtick is the quote character in MySQL; and if it were wrong (syntax error, invalid object name) it would throw an exception.

Comment: @potatow Makes no difference at all, i still receive the else value

Comment: Hey Mark, theres a row named failcounter in it and its type INT

Comment: @user3220962: It is clear from the documentation on `next()` that it returns *`true` if the new current row is valid; `false` if there are no more rows*. On an empty resultset, it is always a *`false`*.

Comment: If you run that query in any database manager what's the result you get? Is it the expected result? Because you must be getting an empty resultset if it always returns -99.

Comment: yep its empty but it shouldnt. im confused xD

Comment: Then the problem is in your query per se, we can't help you there since we have no idea of your database structure. Do you have rows in your randomstuff table?

Comment: I think somethign went wrong there. I just created 2 columns, 'name' and 'anzahl' and i want to insert now failcounter as name nd 0 as anzahl. how would be the insert query for that?

Answer (score 2):

From your comment `I always get -99`

It means that ,

```
if(zrs.next()){
             return zrs.getInt(1);
          }
```

doesnt gets executed . Also understand the differences using `if(zrs.next())` and `while(zrs.next())`

**You usually use "while" as you want to loop through all the data in the result set. You use "if" when the query returns one row by definition**

So in your case the `ResultSet` must be null or the column index might be wrong . so check for the Data in the table first
Hope this helps !

Answer (score -1):

Try you this.

```
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM event"); 
while (res.next()) 
{ 

    int id = res.getInt("id"); 
    String msg = res.getString("msg");
     System.out.println(id + "\t" + msg); 

}
```

And follow more read [How to connect with MySQL database using Java

Read more: [http://mrbool.com/how-to-connect-with-mysql-database-using-java/25440#ixzz30N93JAkm]](http://mrbool.com/how-to-connect-with-mysql-database-using-java/25440#ixzz30N93JAkm%5d)[1](http://mrbool.com/how-to-connect-with-mysql-database-using-java/25440)

Best of Luck!

Comment: How does this answer this specific question?